# How do I overlap PNG images for a "build your own t-shirt" product display page - javascript/css/asp

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing, asp-classic, z-index

I built my CMS with Classic ASP (yeah, I know it is old).
It has a shopping cart and payment system.
I'm adding in the capability for any product to have, in addition to title, price, thumbnail image, etc.: "image for stacking".

So, for example, if you are selling t-shirts, one "product" on the page would be "shirt style" which has it's own PNG associated with it. The next "product" on the same page would be "shirt color". Then "logo" or "text". Each of these items will influence one image over on the left of the page so that these PNGs "stack" to create what the end product will look like.

What I'm weak on is javascript and css. Does anyone have some code or clues to help me out?

Oh and there are hundreds of images so also, please, tips on how to make them load on the fly instead of trying to load in all images when the page loads.

Thank you, fellow programmers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS property `position:absolute` lets you place elements above each other and `z-index` controls the stacking order, so use them to get it all setup right.

Then to load on the fly use javascript to change the `src` of any of the existing element to whatever you need it to be, like this. (using jQuery)

```
<div id="shirt>
    <img id="color" src="blank.png">
    <img id="decal" src="blank.png">
    <img id="logo" src="blank.png">
</div>
```

-

```
$('#color').attr('src','red-shirt.png');
$('#decal').attr('src','lion-decal.png');
$('#logo').attr('src','bold-logo.png');
```

Comment: You may also want to mention `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. Otherwise, the images will never stack on top of one another regardless of `z-index`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! What about dynamic image loading? I guess your solution already takes that into account because the server-build page has only those blank pngs and only when they select an image does the javascript fill those blanks with an image?

Comment: With z-index, is it a problem to assign it values like 10, 20, and 30 or must they be sequential and small like 0, 1, 2, etc.?

Comment: They don't need to be sequential

Answer (score 2):

Use `z-index` to determine which image is on top
And maybe `position:absolute` on one image so that the images will overlap.

But there can be a lot of approach here.
Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/N6rjG/

There you make the t-shirt the background of a div and then you put the selected image inside it. The script is already there and simple.

html:

```
<!-- This one will be the tshirt--->
<div id="tshirt">
</div>

<h1>Click on Image to Select Design</h1>
<!--the choices-->
<img id="d1" class="d" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUomLjtjuA81HKgj48ZaIT6Uvd9JGttmUvVcFO3j3ytp6v6MV0" />

<img id="d2" class="d" src="http://www.ironman2.net/iron-man.jpg" />

<img class="d" src="http://www.unc.edu/~bhamidi/personal/naruto.jpg" />​
```

CSS:

```
#tshirt{
   float:left;
   width:390px;
   height:400px;
   background:url(http://www.schumacher-fanclub.com/media/SFR1119-ferrari-t-shirt-small-scudetto-red.jpg);
}

.d{
    width:100px;
    height:130px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

script:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $("#tshirt").html(' ');
    $(this).clone()
        .appendTo("#tshirt")
        .css({margin:'130px 0 0 150px'});
});​
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm sort of a beginner with javascript and haven't seen those $ symbols before. Curious...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your question is more broad than you might think.

You're probably looking for AJAX in addition to some clever CSS. I recommend you look into jQuery. W3Schools has a very good tutorial. Once you get the basics down, you can set up some basic AJAX to load the image files, and stack them on top of each other. JQuery has a very simple way of working with AJAX, so you shouldn't have any trouble with that once you figure out how jQuery actually works.

From there, you can position each of your image files using CSS. I'd set each as a basic `<img>`, and place them all inside of a `<div>`. From there, look into `position: absolute;` and you can hopefully figure out the rest. If you have more specific questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thank you! I definitely want to use AJAX because I see so much value there. Right now I'm looking for a bit more of a quick fix and wondering if it is possible to do the dynamic loading of images using only Javascript?

Comment: Well, AJAX is still JavaScript--and you need AJAX for this. If you don't want to use jQuery, you're just making things more complicated for yourself. jQuery is still JavaScript, but it's just a faster, more coherent way of getting JavaScript done. Sure, you can work with AJAX without jQuery, but it's much more complicated, and horribly unnecessary.

Comment: OK then I'll go ahead and dive into Ajax. Thanks! Hey do you know: With z-index, is it a problem to assign it values like 10, 20, and 30 or must they be sequential and small like 0, 1, 2, etc.?